# How do you create 2 hotkeys for variations of the same keymap?

Tags: shortcut, operator, pose-mode

I'd like to have 'Flip Active/Selected Bone' and 'Flip Active/Selected Bone' with the 'Extend' checkbox turned on as 2 separate keyboard shortcuts, eg. <kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>.

[image]

Creating a new hotkey works fine. However, the 'Extend' property won't reset when using both hotkeys in succession. Just done a quick video explaining the problem in detail: https://youtu.be/GYPL0GgHI98

**Q:** How could I make both hotkeys work properly?

Comment: I think you can just add a new item to *3D View > Armature > Armature (Global)* copy the operator id `armature.select_mirror` into the identifier field and tick the checkbox to make it work. Does that help?

Comment: Almost yes! Thank you, I've now created a new one with the checkbox ticked but once I use the "extend" hotkey it stays that way, so even if i use the shortcut without the checkbox it stays in extend mode.

Comment: Cool! What do you mean by "it stays that way"? Make sure there is no other hotkey overriding the one you've set. Tested by setting up both hotkeys -> Ctrl+F to call `armature.select_mirror` operator without the property (extend) and Alt+F calling the operator with the property ticked/enabled and it seems to work properly @superduck

Comment: Just done a quick video explaining the problem! https://youtu.be/GYPL0GgHI98